# A follow-up question in a proof in a paper on complete multipartite graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, graph-theory, polynomials

A follow-up question from the following article/paper:

"Proof of a conjecture on distance energy change of complete multipartite graph due to edge deletion"

by Shaowei Sun and Kinkar Chandra Das.

[Paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379520305127?via%3Dihub#!) and DOI: 10.1016/j.laa.2020.10.029.

[image]

**Q1) How does Eqs $(4)$ and $(5)$ imply that $(a+c)-a_1^2$ is a root of $g(y) = 0$?**

**Q2) How are the authors deriving the coefficients of the polynomial $g(y)$?**

Answer (score 0):

**Q1:** Substitute in the definition of $g(y)$ the given relations between $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ and $a,b,c,d$ and find after some algebra that
$$g(y)=\tfrac{1}{16} (y-4 a c) \left(y^2 d+y (8 b+8 d-4 a c)+16 a^2+16 b c (c-a)-16 a c d+16 b^2-32 b d+16 d^2\right).$$
So $g(y)=0$ if $y=4ac=(a+c)^2-a_1^2$, as announced.
**Q2:** This second question has no answer without further information on how $g(y)$ is related to $f(x)$.

Comment: Can you please clarify what more information is needed?

Comment: any information that might relate the equation $f(x)=0$ to the equation $g(y)=0$; the post only contains the statement that $(a+c)^2-a_1^2$ is a root of $g(y)=0$, but obviously there are many functions $g(y)$ for which this statement holds.

Comment: the function $f(x)$ was expressed as $(x^2−ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$ as defined in Eqn $(3)$. and $(a+c)^2-a_1^2$ is nothing but $(a+c)^2 - (a-c)^2$ where $a$ and $c$ are the coefficients. Will this help?

Comment: I'm sorry but if the only information I have is that $(a+c)^2-a_1^2$ is a root of some function $g(y)=0$, without additional info how $y$ is related to $x$ or how $g(y)$ is related to $f(x)$, the second question has no answer (unlike the first question).